# Convert varchar 114 on datetime equals what?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, formatting

I have trouble in setting the equal condition on a datetime field after converting it to `hh:mm:ss.mmm`:

```
select top 1 convert(varchar, timestamp, 114) from TEST_TABLE

/* returns a single entry of 11:33:35:000 */
```

Then I want to find all entries with that timestamp:

```
select * from TEST_TABLE where convert(varchar, timestamp, 114) = '11:33:35.000'

/* returns nothing */
```

I've also tried the format of `'11:33:35'` (without the mmm) on the R.H.S. of the equal sign, no luck. I'm running these queries in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008 if that matters. But I need a way that works cross platform as ultimately I'm running a Perl script to perform the query via the DBI module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`11:33:35:000` is not the same as `11:33:35.000`

try

```
select * 
from TEST_TABLE 
where convert(varchar, timestamp, 114) = '11:33:35:000'
```

I prefer style 108 myself

```
select convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 108)
```

15:29:00

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings, so they have to be exactly the same:

```
select * from TEST_TABLE where convert(varchar, timestamp, 114) = '11:33:35:000'
```

Notice the colon instead of the period in the string literal.